# Linked ArrayList Implementation

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, arraylist, linked-list

I am trying to implement a Linked ArrayList in C++ for instruction purposes, I've hit a snag though and I'm unsure how to unsnag it. My pointer array doesn't seem to be composed of pointers, but of actual objects.

Keeping my code as brief as possible.

//arraylist.h//

```
class classArrayList {
private:
    class Node {
            Node();
            //accessors

    };
    Node* classArray;

public:
    classArrayList();
};
```

//arraylist.cpp//

```
classArrayList::classArrayList() {
    Node* node = new Node();
    this->setHead(node); 
    this->setMaxSize(5);
    classArray = new Node[5];
    this->classArray[0] = *node;
    this->setSize(1);
}

void classArrayList::deleteNode( int index ) {
    Node* my_current = &this->classArray[index];
//blahblah
}
```

But when I go to delete a node, "my_current" doesn't link to whatever would be next or prev in this list. Trying to delete at position zero, no next.

So there's definately a node with data but it doesn't have its links, but checking the debugger my linked list is fine and works, so its whatever the array is pointing to that's screwing up.

So instead of pointing to the list, its pointing to unique instances, how can I fix this?

My code to add something new to the array is: this->classArray[some_index] = *new_node;

To clarify, I wanna be able to have an array that points sequencially to each object in my linked list. And then when I ask for one at any n in my arraylist, reference it to a pointer and then do thins to the object in my list through its position in the array, rather than increment through the list until I find the nth one I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your `classArray` a double pointer and create a `Node` pointer array. `Node* classArray;` Copy the address of head of your list to each array.

```
classArray = new Node*[5];
```

In your code by your statement `this->classArray[0] = *node;` you are not storing the address of the newly created, instead content of newly created node. And by deleting you are not removing the dynamically created list head.

For copying the address of newly created list you should use

```
 this->classArray[0] = node;
```

Comment: Do you mean copying the address of a newly created node? I get a syntax error: "Error no operator matches these operands." I'm also confused by what you mean of copying "head" to each array. I only have 1 head and one list of n size (and tail but thats irrelevant). I just want one array where each element is a point that points to its respective element in the LinkedList. (so that I can access each node from the array at O(1) time and go through the List itself at O(n) if I want to go through it sequentially.

Answer (score 0):

The code works as it should. When you delete a node from your linked list, you delete the data under the pointer. As you set `my_current` to the address of the deleted node, you actually don't point to anything. The problem doesn't lie in the code, but in your understanding of the subject.

In order to really make a working linked list, every node should consist of a pointer to the **next** node. That way, when you delete a node, you'll first be able to retrieve the next node from the pointer, and set your `my_current` to a valid address.

In order to solve your problem, you should actually read a bit about the [subject](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list).

If you want to access the elements in "array style", [overload](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B) the `operator []`.

```
Node& classArrayList::operator [](unsigned int index)
{
   Node *node = head;
   for(unsigned int i=0;i<index;i++)
      if(node->next()) node = node->next();
      else break;
   return *node;
}
```

Comment: My linked list works as it should, it is the array part that doesn't. When I make a pointer equal to where the array index should point to, I just get a unique instance that doesn't actually have a next even when the linked list version does.

Comment: Well you **shouldn't** have an **array** inside a **linked list**. That's why you should read about the subject. I gave you a link in my answer. If you want to access the elements of the linked list with a `[]`, you should overload the `operator []` and do a `for` loop inside it, in which you would do `node=node->next` untill you reach the element with the given index.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense and the wikipedia article doesn't shed any further clarity on what you mean. What does make sense is that there is an array and each element of the way should point to its corresponding element in the LinkedList. That is my understanding of the data structure.

Comment: Added an example code inside the answer. Maybe now it makes sense for you. There's no point in having both an array and a linked list, that store the same data. You end up with a hybrid structure, that's not a linked list, and that isn't an array. If you're doing it for a project - you must've missunderstood the conception behind the data structure. If you need the functionality, use the `std::vector` template class, and all problems will be gone. You can of course do it you way, but have in mind, it's not how it should look in the pure version.

Comment: The hybrid structure is what I want, because that is how I was taught it should work. It has the advantage of an array that I can access its "known" elements in O(1) time, but still iterate through it in O(n). (But the disadvantage that inserting/deleting a node is also O(n). I never understood the impetus behind "Oh just use a standard library" when one is a student, I am learning problem solving, not memorizing tools.

Comment: I said "if you need the functionality". not "if you want to learn how it works". When people actually work on projects, and they don't need to **learn**, but **do**, it's best not to reinvent the wheel.
If you would skip the linked list, and stick with a pure array of pointers, you would get the same effect, without wasting twice as much memory. If you want to learn - check out the `std::string` implementation. It's similar to what you want to do, but it's more cost effective in terms of memory used.

Comment: And if I gave each node of the list a member called "int itsIndex" I'm sure I could get something to that effect as well, but I wouldn't have O(1) time. This is a "real" data structure I was taught last semester, (though the example was Java) and I'ld very much like to recreate that data structure. Can we please get to the actual problem that my array of pointers don't actually point to the list, but point to a separate instance in memory?